# Selecting dates as columns for summary table

Tags: mysql, date

From this example table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE sales
  (`sales_person_id` int, 
   `sale_date` datetime, 
   `sale_amount` int);

INSERT INTO sales
  (`sales_person_id`, `sale_date`, `sale_amount`)
VALUES
  (1, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 10),
  (1, '2014-01-02 00:00:00', 12),
  (2, '2014-01-03 00:00:00', 20),
  (1, '2014-01-03 00:00:00', 15),
  (1, '2014-01-03 00:00:00', 3),
  (3, '2014-01-05 00:00:00', 25)
;
```

[Fiddle for convenience](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b7553)

When using `@startDate = '2014/01/01'` and `@endDate = '2014/01/06'` I would like to return results in this format:

```
ID | 20140101 | 20140102 | 20140103 | 20140104 | 20140105 | 20140106 | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |       10 |       12 |       18 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
2  |        0 |        0 |       20 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
3  |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |       25 |        0 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm sure this can be done in a single query, but I don't have anything close at the moment. I'll edit if I make any progress.

Comment: It's called a pivot what you're doing there. Thousands of questions regarding this on SO.

Comment: ok thanks, found this: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html  reading...